# vim augroup/autocmd: Unexpected EOF while looking for matching '

Tags: vim

Here is the offending autogroup:

```
augroup EJB
    autocmd! EJB
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile  Captain's.log,*.wiki  setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 tabstop=2
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile  Captain's.log,*.wiki  syn match Todo "\<\(TODO\|EJB\)"
    "autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile  Captain's.log,*.wiki  setlocal commentstring=// %s
    " Scroll to end of file on opening, then find the last non-blank line.
    autocmd BufRead             Captain's.log,*.wiki  :normal! G{}
augroup END
```

If I now open Captain's.log in a console (openSuSE 13.2 KDE konsole/yakuake) vim session - but not a gvim window - then I get this artifact at the bottom of the vim buffer:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

but it disappears as soon as I scroll to that line of the display.

If I add in (uncomment) the commentstring line, then bash gives me a full-on error:

```
"Captain's.log" 2185L, 157386C
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "Captain's.log":
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Line 2185 is just the end of the file.

I have tried escaping the apostrophe in the filename in the augroup with `\'` and `''` (ie. double single-quotes), and have tried single-/double-quoting the filename, to no avail. The first two don't change the error, and the latter two make the pattern not match.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: As @FDinoff suggests, it appears that bash is trying to execute Captain's.log. But I figure that the problem has still got to be a bug in the parsing of vimrc - I just copied-and-renamed the file to Captains.log and updated the autogroup accordingly, and the error goes away.
So obviously I now have a workaround. But I would nonetheless be interested in a full explanation of and fix for the problem.

Comment: What is in Captain's.log, and why are you executing it in bash?

Comment: Your `autocmd` is fine, except that you need to escape the space in `commentstring` (but that's on a commented line anyway).  The error you're seeing is likely to come from a plugin.  Try disabling plugins in turn to locate the problem.

Comment: lc047 is quite correct. (Except that I have 22 plugins, so I did a binary search - disabling half, and then half of those, etc, according to whether the problem manifested or not -, rather than disabling them one at a time.) It was the vim-konsole plugin. I'll look at its source to determine the source of the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: UPDATE: The issue was an unquoted/unescaped use of the filename (%).